# Pester 5 default output way to long stacktrace

Tags: powershell, automated-tests, pester

I just started using pester but recognized some weird behaviour when a test fails.
I wrote this really basic pester script with 2 tests, one passing, one failing.

BasicPester.tests.ps1

```
Describe 'Basic Pester Tests' {
  It 'A test that should be true' {
    $true | Should -Be $true
  }
  It 'A test that should fail' {
    $false | Should -Be $true
  }
}
```

I would assume the default ouput should look like this:

```
Starting discovery in 1 files.
Discovery found 2 tests in 17ms.
Running tests.
[-] Basic Pester Tests.A test that should fail 9ms (7ms|2ms)
 Expected $true, but got $false.
 at $false | Should -Be $true, C:\Code\work\pester_demo\BasicPester.tests.ps1:6
Tests completed in 214ms
Tests Passed: 1, Failed: 1, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 0
```

But actually it outputs way longer stacktrace and somehow in german(my system language):

```
Starting discovery in 1 files.
Discovery found 2 tests in 17ms.
Running tests.
[-] Basic Pester Tests.A test that should fail 9ms (7ms|2ms)
 Expected $true, but got $false.
 at $false | Should -Be $true, C:\Code\work\pester_demo\BasicPester.tests.ps1:6
 bei Invoke-Assertion, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.psm1: Zeile 8078
 bei Should<End>, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.psm1: Zeile 8016
 bei <ScriptBlock>, C:\Code\work\pester_demo\BasicPester.tests.ps1: Zeile 6
 bei <ScriptBlock>, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.psm1: Zeile 1988
 bei <ScriptBlock>, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.psm1: Zeile 1949
 bei Invoke-ScriptBlock, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.psm1: Zeile 2110
 bei Invoke-TestItem, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.psm1: Zeile 1184
 bei Invoke-Block, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.psm1: Zeile 826
 bei <ScriptBlock>, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.psm1: Zeile 881
 bei <ScriptBlock>, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.psm1: Zeile 1988
 bei <ScriptBlock>, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.psm1: Zeile 1949
 bei Invoke-ScriptBlock, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.psm1: Zeile 2113
 bei Invoke-Block, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.psm1: Zeile 928
 bei <ScriptBlock>, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.psm1: Zeile 881
 bei <ScriptBlock>, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.psm1: Zeile 1988
 bei <ScriptBlock>, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.psm1: Zeile 1949
 bei Invoke-ScriptBlock, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.psm1: Zeile 2113
 bei Invoke-Block, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.psm1: Zeile 928
 bei <ScriptBlock>, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.psm1: Zeile 1662
 bei <ScriptBlock>, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.ps1: Zeile 3
 bei <ScriptBlock>, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.psm1: Zeile 3154
 bei Invoke-InNewScriptScope, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.psm1: Zeile 3161
 bei Run-Test, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.psm1: Zeile 1665
 bei Invoke-Test, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.psm1: Zeile 2465
 bei Invoke-Pester<End>, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\pester\5.3.0\Pester.psm1: Zeile 5225
 bei <ScriptBlock>, <Keine Datei>: Zeile 1
Tests completed in 214ms
Tests Passed: 1, Failed: 1, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 0
```

I'm using Pester 5.3.0 on Windows 10 with Powershell 5.1.
Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Pester option `ShowFullErrors` is in play. Is there a profile active that configures this option?

Try invoking pester with this option set to `$false`:

```
PS> $config = New-PesterConfiguration
PS> $config.Run.Path = "<test script>"
PS> $config.Debug.ShowFullErrors = $false
PS> Invoke-Pester -Configuration $config
```

Comment: tried with the new config but I still get the full stacktrace. 
when I check with `[PesterConfiguration]::Default.Debug` its set to `$false`

Comment: If `[PesterConfiguration]::Default.Output.StackTraceVerbosity` is set to `"Full"`, the stack is also display in full (default value is `"Filtered"`)

Answer (score 0):

Since I started using Pester recently and ran into the same problem, try this change to your configuration object:

```
$config.Output.StackTraceVerbosity = "FirstLine"
```